# ol.interaction.Select -> icon disappears

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I use ol.interaction.Select but when fly over feature, my icon disappears.

```
 var selectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
       condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
       style: []
 });
```

What should I put in style to keep my basic icon?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `style:[]` from the above code or create a style object.

If you see the documentation of `ol.interaction.Select`http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html

It clearly says `style` property will be applied for selected Features. Since in your code you have declared an empty style object so the feature is not getting displayed.

**Fix :**

```
var selectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
       condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response but if no style, I have a blue point

For example : [My Map with icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqXnB.jpg)

[When my pointer is on icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qAiK.jpg)

I want just my icon, no blue point... I have many feature with different icon.

Comment: When you select a feature that would be rendered using style property declared while creating `ol.interaction.Select`. Since nothing is declared it is taking default styling. First tell me why you are using Select for what purpose?